# xpath tested and correct but i recieve the error : no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

My Xpath is correct & no iFrame and I can locate element in Chrome console but my program still fails. I have used explicit wait also.

no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@ng-click,'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()')]"}

i tested my xpath with Try xpath and it works but when i compile my code i still recieve the error

the page Object :

```
    package com.orange.pageObject;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.CacheLookup;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class MageReferentiel {
    
    WebDriver webdriver;

    public MageReferentiel(WebDriver rwebDriver) {
        webdriver = rwebDriver;
        PageFactory.initElements(webdriver, this);
    }
    
    
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@ng-click,'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()')]")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement connexion;
    
    
    
    public void clickConnexion() {
            connexion.click();
    }
```

The step definition :

```
@When("l utilisateur choisi le referentiel")
    public void l_utilisateur_choisi_le_referentiel() throws Exception {
        mr.clickConnexion();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
```

im looking to click in button

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Prophet, it could be because of some JS call the button, `//*[contains(@ng-click,'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()')]` changing it's state to some other state. so what we can do about is that, to try with different locator.

such as :

```
//button[@translate ='LOGIN']
```

and see if that works, even if it doesn't try changing it to css.

Comment: in fact I have two panels for each i have the same text name and properties , each represents an application but to access the second panel you have to click on the second connection button to go to the home page and after that I will start the tests on the forms

Comment: //button[@translate ='LOGIN'] it doesn't work to me but the xpath (//button[contains(text(),'Connexion')])[2] it work just on devtools in my eclipse i have the same error

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `ng-click` attribute value is dynamically updated on the page, so when you trying to access that element this element is changed, not having it's initial state.
Instead of locator you are using try this XPath:

```
//button[contains(text(),'Connexion')]
```

or this

```
//button[@translate='LOGIN']
```

The second element with this locator will be

```
(//button[@translate='LOGIN'])[2]
```

Comment: so what i am supposed to do  ?

Comment: but the problem is that i have two button with the same text 'Connexion' and then same properties i try it with adding the index of button like //button[contains(text(),'Connexion')][1] but it doesn't work, thanks

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//button[@translate='LOGIN'])[2]"}

Comment: What is about `(//button[contains(text(),'Connexion')])[2]` ?

Comment: yep sir this is the xpath that I tried (//button[contains(text(),'Connexion')])[2]

Comment: Maybe iframe is there? or missing some delay before getting the element?

Comment: in fact I have two panels for each i have the same text name and properties , each represents an application but to access the second panel you have to click on the second connection button to go to the home page and after that I will start the tests on the forms ... yesterday I have check if I work with an iframe but no

Comment: by the way i tried this (//button[contains(text(),'Connexion')])[2] on try xpath and it works he can locate the button that i want to click but in eclipse it doesn't work

Comment: thanks, yes in dev tools (try xpath for firefox)

Comment: but on eclipse it's not the same case

Answer (score 0):

The default wait strategy in selenium is just that the page is loaded.

You've got an angular page so after your page is loaded there is a short delay while the JS runs and the element is finally ready in the DOM - this delay is causing your script to fail.

Check out the selenium docs here for [wait strategies](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/) .

Your options are:

1. An explicit wait - This needs to be set per element you need to sync on.

I note you say you've used an explicit wait - but where?  - It's not present in the code you shared and it might be that you've used the wrong expected condition.

Try something like this:

```
WebElement button = new WebDriverWait(rwebDriver, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(@ng-click,'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()')]")));
button.click();
```

2. Use an implicit wait - you only use this once when you initialise driver and it will wait the specified amount of time for all element interaction.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

There are other reasons that selenium returns a NoSuchElement but synchronisation is the most common one. Give the wait a go and let me know if it is still giving you trouble.

---

Through discussion in the comments, the trouble is an `iframe`

If you google it - there are lots of answers out there.

With frames, you need to identify it, switch to it, do your action(s) then switch back:

```
//find and switch - update the By.
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("your frame id")));

//actions go here

//back to normal
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: I did both steps and I have this error :  Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[contains(@ng-click,'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()')] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: and also this error : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@ng-click,'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()')]"}

Comment: @jerando The next thing to check is if site is paging - IS your element is available on the page as the test fails? Do you need to scroll it into view?    - If you're checking devtools manually you may be doing this without realising.    What you need to do is add a breakpoint on the failing line and know the state of the DOM as it fails before you do any interaction with it.

Comment: yep sir exactly there are a lot of divs and my site is paging. ok i will try to do that and i will keep you informed. Thanks

Comment: Hello, after add a breakpoint  and following your instructions the probleme is on the function clickConnexion() but i have no idea how can resolve it

Comment: i tried to fixed it also with a cssSelector but it doesn't work, you told that exist other reasons that selenium returns a NoSuchElement can you explain please ?

Comment: @jerando The 3 reasons are iframe/frame, paging and synchronisation. You slightly missed the point of debugging. Breakpoint on the line you know is faulty - at that point, go to chrome, don't interact with the application at all(!), hit f12 to open devtools and manually investigate if your xpath is found. Selenium says it's not - so you see look at what selenium sees in that state .  If you scroll or click on the application you will change it's state so be careful when taking control

Comment: how can i do to investigate if my xpath founded or not ? in Element or Console ?

Comment: @jerando in the elements view.  Run the the breakpoint, go to chrome, f12, select the elements tab, press ctrl+f  to open the search bar then enter your xpath and see if you get a hit

Comment: hello @RichEwards , thanks for your feedback, i I found the button with the xpath : //*[contains(@ng-click,'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()')] without intercting with the application ,i can see it the element is available it's the button that i want to click but even with adding the webDriverWait or implicit wait i can't click on it

Comment: i have this error : Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: Proxy element for: DefaultElementLocator 'By.xpath: //*[contains(@ng-click,'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()')]'

Comment: and  no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@ng-click,'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()')]"}

Comment: @jerando if chrome can find it, it's not paging. But chrome can search inside any part of the page, selenium needs to be told here.. Are you sure there are no frames, iframes or other containers such as a shadow dom?

Comment: 1 - i do not see any iframe in my code html

Comment: my bad there is an iframe in my code html, sorry

Comment: in case of iframe what im supposed to do ?

Comment: No worries -  i'll update the answer - give me a min

Comment: but sir , the iframe is not on the div that i worked on

Comment: Is it the div or button nested at any level under the iframe?

Comment: i updated the question look at the second image the div where there is the button is the last with the id='mage' and the frame is just below the <body>

Comment: Is that second image the top of the dom or is there anything more above it?

Comment: it's all normally we see the header

Comment: I do not know where the problem comes from

Comment: even with iframe i have problem always with xpath he doesn't recognize him

Answer (score 0):

Since `ng` elements are going very well with Protractor (Angular), better to use in Protractor in that case, so it suppose to be something like `element(by.click('authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage').click();`

Comment: can you explain to me please what is "element" ?

Comment: @jerando `element` its like `driver find` and because it's angular there is special locators of that

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the element is not rendering on time. Try using explicit wait. Following gif shows how it is done using Cucumber:

https://nocodebdd.live/waitime-cucumber

Same been implemented using NoCodeBDD:
https://nocodebdd.live/waittime-nocodebdd

Disclaimer: I am the founder of NoCodeBDD so BDD automation can be achieved in minutes and without code. Through NoCodeBDD you could automate majority of the scenarios and it allows you to write your own code if there are edge cases. Would love to get some feedback on the product from the community. Basic version (https://www.nocodebdd.com/download) is free to use.

Comment: the software NoCodeBDD how can that help me to solve my problem?

Comment: NoCodeBDD has an explicit wait time by default. But depending on the rendering speed, you could add wait time without code. As I have mentioned in my post the same thing could be done using Cucumber.

Comment: it didn't work for me i have this error Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[contains(@ng-click,'authenticationCtrl.onSubmitMage()')]